# rollup doesn't succeed for angular2-busy, 'BusyModule' is not exported by .../index.js

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

AOT build succeeds, but rollup step fails:

```
'BusyModule' is not exported by node_modules\angular2-busy\index.js
...
34: import { BusyModule } from 'angular2-busy';
             ^
```

index.js:

```
export * from './build/index';
```

build/index.js:

```
"use strict";
function __export(m) {
    for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
}
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__export(require("./busy.module"));
__export(require("./busy.directive"));
__export(require("./busy.service"));
__export(require("./busy-config"));
```

rollup-config.js:

```
export default {
    entry: 'src/main-aot.js',
    dest: 'dist/build.js',
    sourceMap: false,
    format: 'iife',
    onwarn: function(warning) {
        ...
    },
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
        commonjs({
            include: [
                'node_modules/**'
            ]
        })
]
}
```

I've tried to use namedExports:

```
namedExports: {
                'node_modules/angular2-busy/build/busy.module.js': [ 'BusyModule' ]
            }
```

With no luck:

```
?   Duplicate export 'BusyModule'
node_modules\angular2-busy\build\busy.module.js (87:26)
85: export { busy_module_2 as createJitCompiler };
86: var busy_module_3 = busy_module.BusyModule;
87: export { busy_module_3 as BusyModule };
                              ^
```

Does anyone knows how to deal with it?

Thanks.